# Lumia-bxslider in Wordpress (lumia-bxslider wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using "D5 Socialia" theme Version 1.2.8, WordPress 3.7 and installed lumia-bxslider slider plugin to my site.

I encountered these issues:

```
- Height which I set from admin panel doesn't work.
- Now bullets or next previous button is appeared.
- I can not understand the functionality of.

  ->Prev Images Path    
  ->Next Images Path    
  ->Pager Images Path   
  ->Pager Active Images Path
```

Above given options in lumia-bxslider plugin settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by this time you have already solved this issue. But probably somebody will come
across it in the future.

So just like most slider plugins, you may override the default css, images and etc.

Below is for your question.

->Prev Images Path : The path to the image icon. (i.e. /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/imagefolder/usual_left_arrow_icon.png)

->Next Images Path : The path to the image icon. (i.e. /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/imagefolder/usual_right_arrow_icon.png)

->Pager Images Path : The path to the image icon. (i.e. /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/imagefolder/bullets_inactive.png)

->Pager Active Images Path : The path to the image icon. (i.e. /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/imagefolder/bullets_active_usually_blue_or_black.png)

Regarding the height, the developer noted that sizes are determined by getting the image size/dimension and the plugin does not resize images. If really needed, I recommend that you download a mass image re-sizer plugin or use Wordpress' core image editor.

If there's no images appearing, you may have entered an incorrect path. I assume that you are getting 404 error from your browser's developer console.

I suggest that you always get the updated plugin.

Below are the links for updating it:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/lumia-bxslider/

https://github.com/wp-plugins/lumia-bxslider